# closing open handles detected by jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

i am writting tests for a node application which uses `bull` to process background jobs.

the test seems to be passing and working as expected but i am seeing the following error message

```
Jest has detected the following 
8 open handles potentially keeping 
Jest from exiting:
```

the log points to specifically this line and other similar statements.

```
 const csvExportsQueue = ['test', 'development'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV) ? new Queue('exports') : new Queue('csv exports', 'redis://redis:6379/13');
```

I tried to add the below statement to my test but it still gives the same error

```
afterAll(async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 10000)); // avoid jest open handle error
});
```

any help on how to fix this will be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. add "jest --detectOpenHandles" to "test" in package.json to see the openhandles for Debugging
2. check your db connection (most likely) and close it them with connection.end()

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the application actually does not use any database at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use either [why-is-node-running](https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running) or [wtfnode](https://github.com/myndzi/wtfnode) to find where these handles are.
2. Run the `jest` with these arguments:

```
jest --forceExit --detectOpenHandles
```